# obtaining the url of a video with its blob key

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I tried the code below to get the serving url for a video saved on app engine's cloud storage. It threw `TransformationError`.

```
public_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
```

I'm using python 2.7. Is there a solution?

Comment: How can you save a video on App Engine? Do you mean Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1):

The [images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) API is for processing photos/still images, not videos. Feeding it a video is very likely the reason why you're getting `TransformationError`.

It is possible to serve/stream videos as well, plenty of related SO material: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-app-engine]+video+streaming

Comment: how do I get the same effect for videos?

Comment: what do you mean by "same effect"? transformations? getting a serving url? something else?

Comment: I meant getting a serving url. I have solved it though. Thanks for your help